# python - read csv file from last line

Tags: python, csv

I searched quite a bit, but I could not find a way to read the data from a csv file from a particular line number.

The csv file gets updated on the fly. To be more precise the delimiter is a tab space
so, at time t1:

```
1 2 3
5 6 7
8 9 10
11 12 13
14 15 16
```

at time t2 it is

```
1 2 3
5 6 7
8 9 10
11 12 13
14 15 16
17 18 19
```

I have a collection(deque) in which I want to append the data from coloumn0 the csv file.

at the moment the code I have written is able to do this:
at time 0:

```
[deque([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], maxlen=5)]
```

at time 1:

```
[deque(['1', '5', '8', '11', '14'])]
```

at time 2:

```
[deque(['5', '8', '11', '14','17'])]
```

The code i've scripted is reading it in the format I want.

```
Question:
```

but when I reopen the file again at some point 'x'. it should read from

```
[deque(['8', '11', '14','17','x'])]
```

and not

```
[deque(['1', '5', '8', '11', '14'])]
```

and is it possible for me to read one line and jump to the next file? is there a library that will allow me to do this?

am I clear? or am I missing out to give some information?

Updating the answer to this question by taking the input from kurtis(all credits to him):

```
perf_his = []

for a in range(len(filename)):
 perf_his += [deque([0]*5,maxlen=5)]
for a in range(len(filename)):
 lines = open(filename[a]).readlines()[-NUM_LINES:]
 mydata = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]
 for i in range(0, len(mydata)):
  perf_his[a].append(mydata[i])
   print perf_his
```

Comment: You might consider adapting http://code.google.com/p/pytailer/

Comment: I find it confusing to know why you'd want to reopen the file, why not just reuse the file handle.  To reopen at 'x' would seem that you'd want line of 'x' .. line of 'x' + 5, as for line 1 you read 5 lines of data but your example for 'x' shows it last. Is it that you want to take from the dequeue, yet when new data is detected from csvreader you want it appended to the dequeue. How would you know when there's no more data to be added to the CSV file?

Comment: I have multiple files that I have to keep reading on the fly. in order to do that, i need to close one file handler and then reopen another one. right?
the quit the program and it automatically ensures that there is no more data written out to the csv file.

Comment: @user2015933 "I searched quite a bit, but I could find a way..."  Then, why do you post ?

Comment: that's obviously a typo. I apologize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually want to read the file backwards?  From what you have posted it looks like you just want to process the last 5 lines -- otherwise instead of deque(['5', '8', '11', '14','17']) at t2 you would have deque(['17', '14', '11', '8', '5']).

Assuming that what you really want to do is just process the last 5 lines, you could do something like this --

```
from collections import deque

NUM_LINES=5 #The number of lines to process.  Should equal the deque maxlen    

lines = open("myfile.csv").readlines()[-NUM_LINES:] #Assumes the file can fit into memory
mydata = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]
d = deque(mydata, maxlen=NUM_LINES)
print d
```

Comment: I am sorry for the delayed reply. I want to process the last five line of the first coloumn in the csv file. Let me try your code out.